# C#: WinForms Numeric Spinner not updating trackbar

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I'm having a very small and specific problem. I am trying to establish a 2-way relation between my **Trackbar** and my **NumericUpDown** controls. Basically moving the **Trackbar** should update the value in the **NumericUpDown** control and vice versa in case users want a more direct input.

Based on the context of the question, this is the kind of code I have:

```
        //Updates Stamp Position Upon Scrolling Trackbar
    private void xSlider_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double temp = (xSlider.Value*(paperPanel.Width-stampPreview.Width))/100;
        int newX = (int)temp;

        stampPreview.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(newX, stampPreview.Location.Y);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(xSlider.Value);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(stampPreview.Location.X);

        this.Invalidate();

        xSpinner.Value = xSlider.Value;
    }


    //Updates Stamp Position Upon Scrolling Trackbar
    private void ySlider_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double temp = (ySlider.Value * (paperPanel.Height - stampPreview.Height)) / 100;
        int newY = (int)temp;

        stampPreview.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(stampPreview.Location.X, newY);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ySlider.Value);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(stampPreview.Location.Y);

        this.Invalidate();
        ySpinner.Value = ySlider.Value;
    }


    //Updates Stamp Position when NumericUpDown Control is Altered
    private void xSpinner_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        xSlider.Value = (int)xSpinner.Value;
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    //Updates Stamp Position when NumericUpDown Control is Altered
    private void ySpinner_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ySlider.Value = (int)ySpinner.Value;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
```

The issue is, the controls are behaving perfectly when moving either of the X-direction controls. However, even though the Y-direction has the EXACT same code, the **NumericUpDown** control simply does not reflect changes on the **Trackbar**, and hence does not update my object's position. However, moving the Y-direction **Trackbar DOES move the object**. I also note that I am using the same event for both, so what exactly am I missing for that trigger to fail?

Comment: You are using the **same** event? Isn't that the reason for the error? Can you show where you register the event handlers (just for completeness)?

Comment: And did you try to debug it? You could set breakpoints in the handlers to see what happens and what goes wrong.

Comment: @ René Vogt  Sorry the poor wording -- my understanding is, the **ValueChanged** is an event for the control. Under the properties of the Numeric control, I go to events and double click on "ValueChanged". I would assume that means any code I put inside that block will be executed whenever the value of the spinner changes. I did the same for the second spinner. That's as far as I can go with my limited knowledge of the language.

Answer (score 0):

After more scrutiny, it turns out using the "**Scroll**" event isn't the ideal way to handle the situation. Basically incrementing the numeric changes the value of the **Trackbar** but doesn't scroll it, hence the code doesn't execute properly. Oddly enough, the X-Position worked fine because I DID in fact use a **ValueChanged** event that coincidentally (and mistakenly) was labeled as **xSlider_Scroll**.